# How to make string replacement in a JSON template?

Tags: json, templates, jq, template-engine

If I have a JSON template in which some variable should be replaced with their actual value, is there a good way to handle the proper escape?

For example, `$value` may be replaced with a string that contains characters like `"` that should be treated specially in JSON.

```
{ "x": $value }
```

The template could be arbitrary complex. So it is not a good solution to code the template in some programming language like python, then perform the replacement in that language, then dump the JSON output.

Could anybody show me a generic but succinct way to perform the replacement?

Note that I tagged this question with `jq`. I am not sure it is strictly relevant to this question. If not, please remove the tag. I tagged `jq` because people who know `jq` may also know solutions to my question, although jq is just for transforming a JSON file. An elegant solution may be similar to `jq` in the sense that a domain-specific language is defined.

Answer (score 2):

jq works quite nicely as a template engine, but there are choices to be made, e.g. depending on whether the "template" itself is valid JSON.

In the example you gave, the template is not valid JSON, but it is potentially valid jq, so the strategy using jq "$-variables" would make sense, e.g. along the lines of:

```
jq -n --arg value "someValue" -f template.jq
```

where `template.jq` is your template.

Three different strategies for using jq as a template engine are explained at some length in the jq Cookbook:

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#using-jq-as-a-template-engine

Comment: For the example, `$ jq -n --argjson a 0 -f <(echo '{a: $a, b: $a}')`, the template is specified by `-f` from a unamed pipe. Is there a way to specify it from stdin?

Comment: Not really, unless you allow `-f <(cat -)` or equivalent.  It doesn't really matter, though, does it?